# Dictionary Iteration

Tags: python

I'm given this dataset and tasked with coming up with a loop to find the highest value in this dictionary. I'm confused with why by placing the print function inside the loop(#1) produces a different answer from placing it outside the loop(#2).

```
data = {'Jeremy':73284, 'Hansel':8784.3, 'Uee':9480938.2,
        'Seolhyun':984958.3, 'Ketsuno Ana':24131, 'Trump':45789}

highest_network = data["Jeremy"]

for key,value in data.items():
    if value > highest_network:
        highest_network = value
        print(key,value) #1 


print(key,value) #2
```

Sorry, I'm still a beginner in python hence I am still not very familiar with some concept.

Comment: Can you provide the examples of what you're seeing when printing inside the loop versus outside, and what you're expecting to see?

Comment: Hi tlbignerd, im expected to get a result of 'Uee: 9480938.2' as it is the biggest value in the dictionary set. I get the result if print it in #1, however if I were to print it outside the loop(#2), I get a result of 'Trump:45789'

Comment: It's because the `key` and `value` used in the `print(key,value) #2` state executes **after** the loop has finished, so you're seeing the _last_ values the loop assigned to each of them.

Comment: Your code works to find the highest value in a dictionary, but since you're a beginner, you may find this alternative one-line approach helpful: `max(data.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])`. This takes advantage of the optional `key` parameter of the built-in `max` function and finds the tuple with the greatest value in index position 1.

Answer (score 1):

At any given time during execution, python keeps what's essentially a dictionary of variable names that exist, and their values. The way this interacts with scope is kind of confusing/complicated, but suffice it to say that in this situation, `key` and `value` are declared in a scope that is *outside their `for` loop*.

Now, note the first `print` statement. Since it's inside the loop, and the `key` and `value` are going to be constantly updating, it will print the current `key` and `value` every time it's executed.

The second `print` statement is outside the loop, and is executed *after* the loop has run. Keep in mind that the variables `key` and `value` are *still in scope*, and still hold whatever the last things assigned to them are (in this case, `key` and `value` will be the last value you'd get from `data.items()`). This is why they behave differently - because the value of `key` and `value` are different every time you try printing them.

Keep in mind that the order in which `data.items()` puts the data is effectively arbitrary, as far as the standards are concerned. The order in which each key is put through that `for` loop will be consistent from run to run *on your machine*, but if you put the same code on someone else's machine it might act differently. As a result, you should not rely on this behavior being consistent.

Comment: Thanks! It was rather detailed explanation regarding the situation. That explains why I get the last key in the dictionary, whenever I was to print the key and value outside of the loop. Greatly appreciate your inputs!

Answer (score 0):

The first `print` statement is inside an conditional branch and inside the for loop.
Therefore, every time the condition given by the `if` statement is `True` the `print` function gets executed. Now, given your data, this holds only for the case of `"Uee"`, whose value has the largest value, and also is the first value to be larger than `"Jeremy"`. Also note that the order which `items()` return does not have to be the same every time so you can get also different results and the first `print` can be executed many times.

Now, the second `print` is outside the for loop, which means that the `key` and `value` variables hold the last value they were assigned. Again, this could be anything from the dictionary, since the ordering returned by `items()` does not have to be the same. In case the dictionary is traversed in the order specified in the example, it would print the `"trump"` entry.